# powerline-status makes zsh hg (mercurial) branch info disappear from the prompt, yet the git prompt info remains

Tags: zsh, prompt, mercurial

To be a poweruser these days, you have to have a tricked out shell. One of the most common custom shells is `zsh` with the **Oh my zsh** plugin manager.
`sudo apt install zsh` then installed oh-my-zsh per curl, then ran `zsh`

Adding

```
# ~/.zshrc:
plugins=(git mercurial)
```

gets me the mercurial status in my command prompt.

But when I install powerline: `sudo -H pip install powerline-status; sudo apt install python-hglib`

And load it in

```
# ~/.zshrc:
. `locate powerline.zsh`
```

to `~/.zshrc`

Then the prompt loses mercurial status. I should note it still works fine for `git` repos, so it's a mercurial only issue... And the other features of powerline is fine, and no errors. Removing powerline from my zsh config brings the mercurial info back, so it's definitely caused by powerline.

Comment: Could be related: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1675

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I wish the *.deb for powerline handled ZSH (Not sure how to get it to work). In any case, the solution was to do:

`sudo apt install python3-hglib` instead of `sudo apt install python-hglib`